# iOS 11.1.1 lock screen always shows iTunes controls. How do I disable this bug / feature?

Tags: iphone, ios

After upgrading my iPhone to iOS 11.1.1, the locked screen shows iTunes music prominently covering my lock-screen picture, whereas before this never happened.

I'd like to disable this feature / bug, but I don't see any mechanism for doing so.

Does everyone's iOS 11.1.1 do this, or is it just a bug that randomly hits people?

I would like to see my picture, not iTunes, which I rarely use.  I also don't want to accidentally hit "play" and start random noises from my pocket.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, although I haven't updated. Have you tried unlocking then relocking the phone, closing Music, or rebooting?

Comment: Thanks @seaturtle. I rebooted the phone already and saw it was no longer manifesting. I am not sure what caused it to start up, but it was that way ever since upgrading to 11.1.1 last night.

Comment: Wonderful. A simple reboot fixes _so_ many wacky things.

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting the iPhone resolved this issue, and it has yet to re-appear.

This appears to be a temporary manifestation of a bug, one which I was unable to find any references to online.